# Win32: Any way to allocate memory range and have traps on specific pages?

Tags: windows, cpu, paging

I was wondering if Windows exposes an API that allows a user-mode process to allocate a chunk of address space and then install "traps" on specific pages of this space, so that if these pages are accessed (read/written) by the process, then Windows will call a handler in the program, for instance by invoking a callback function or throwing an exception that can be handled by the program? I think this should be possible for Windows to implement by setting up the page tables to trigger page faults on the relevant pages. Then, if the memory is accessed this will trigger a page fault by the CPU, which the page fault handler can reflect back to the program. But I don't know if Windows actually offers this functionality.

By the way, is the functionality supported in Linux?

Comment: Use `VirtualProtect' to revoke access to the page, and then install a vectored exception handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting Raymond's answer/comment:

"Use `VirtualProtect' to revoke access to the page, and then install a vectored exception handler."